# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating cl

Tags: android

I have this error in my project: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView. this error indexing this line : setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
this is my Home page

package com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        //here is the main place where we need to work on.
        int id=item.getItemId();
        switch (id){

            case R.id.home:
                Intent h= new Intent(Home.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(h);
                break;
            case R.id.login:
                Intent i= new Intent(Home.this,Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.recherche:
                Intent g= new Intent(Home.this,Recherche.class);
                startActivity(g);
                break;

            // this is done, now let us go and intialise the home page.
            // after this lets start copying the above.
            // FOLLOW MEEEEE>>>
        }



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is the app_bar_home:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this the activity_home:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is the content_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Home"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the nav_header_home:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/h4"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <!--<ImageView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/imageView"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="95dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="70dp"-->
        <!--android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"-->
        <!--android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"-->
        <!--app:srcCompat="@drawable/tof" />-->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

this the style:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />



</resources>
```

finaly this the logcat:

```
07-26 09:51:01.386 4512-4512/com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-26 09:51:01.386 4512-4512/com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy, PID: 4512
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy/com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy.Home.onCreate(Home.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy.Home.onCreate(Home.java:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy.Home.onCreate(Home.java:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:267)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:176)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:98)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy.Home.onCreate(Home.java:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:267) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:176) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:98) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy.Home.onCreate(Home.java:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:267) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:176) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:98) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tiakocedrick.eateasy.Home.onCreate(Home.java:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFo
07-26 09:56:01.738 4512-4512/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4512 SIG: 9
```

Comment: show us your activity_home.xml

Comment: please post full stack trace and xml layout

Comment: show also nav_header_home.xml and menu activity_home_drawer.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency in your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```